# php mysql: syntax date with hour

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the data starting at 23 on the previous day until 01 o'clock.

```
$query=mysql_query("select fe1a.* from fe1a WHERE fe1a.waktu_fe1a >= '%$tanggal_awal%' 
23:00:00 + INTERVAL -1 DAY  AND fe1a.waktu_fe1a <  '%$tanggal_awal%' 01:00:00 ");
```

and i use `'%$tanggal_awal%'`  To catch date value from calendar `tanggal_awal=$_POST['tanggal_awal'];`

It's not working. I think there is a mistake in the syntax, `'%$tanggal_awal%'` 23:00:00. It work if i change the script to `WHERE fe1a.waktu_fe1a >= '%$tanggal_awal%'` or WHERE `fe1a.waktu_fe1a like '%$tanggal_awal%'` or something without hour.

```
fe1a.waktu_fe1a datetime
```

can you help me correct this syntax?

Comment: if possible to change the db field please change the datatime type to timestamp data type. it's easiest way for data functionality....

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("
     select fe1a.* 
     from 
       fe1a 
     WHERE 
         fe1a.waktu_fe1a >= '$tanggal_awal 23:00:00' + INTERVAL -1 DAY
     AND 
         fe1a.waktu_fe1a <  '$tanggal_awal 01:00:00' ");
```

You don't need the `%` sign.

Comment: i use this :   $query=mysql_query("select fe1a.* from fe1a WHERE fe1a.waktu_fe1a >= DATE_FORMAT ('%$tanggal_awal%','%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00') + INTERVAL -1 DAY  AND fe1a.waktu_fe1a < DATE_FORMAT ('%$tanggal_awal%','%Y-%m-%d 01:00:00')");  it does not work

Comment: replace  `DATE_FORMAT ('%$tanggal_awal%','%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00)` with  `DATE_FORMAT ('$tanggal_awal','%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00)`.
Refer: [Date Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: @DumdumDumDum Can you tell me what errors are you getting while executing the query

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: It work if i change the script to $query=mysql_query("select fe1a.* from fe1a WHERE fe1a.waktu_fe1a >= '%$tanggal_awal%' ");

Comment: @DumdumDumDum And what date format value is stored in `$tanggal_awal`?

Comment: mmmm-yy-dd; it is catching date value from calendar

Comment: @DumdumDumDum : it should be `yyyy-mm-dd`. There are only 12 months in a year

Comment: @DumdumDumDum: ok, so if you are saying its working with '%$tanggal_awal%' , its means that your variable is already in he format `Y-m-d H:i:s` and you don't need to explicitly mention `23:00:00` in the query.